# How to add authorization token in a url

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add the bearer token in a URL and send me the HTML response and then when  i am trying to redirect the URL it gives me empty headers how can i solve the problem

```
let ratingurl ="https:xyz.com/wr?uid=VSHvFAon4QU"
    var xhrreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhrreq.open("GET", ratingurl, true);
                xhrreq.withCredentials = false;
                xhrreq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
                xhrreq.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')
                xhrreq.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `${headerToken}`)
                xhrreq.onreadystatechange = function () {
                   if (xhrreq.readyState === 4) {
                      console.log(xhrreq.status);
                      console.log(xhrreq.response);
                      //  window.location.href = 'https:xyz.com/wr?uid=VSHvFAon4QU'
                   }};
                
                xhrreq.send();
```

I want to know how to add the token in a URL and then with the added token how can i redirect

Comment: It would help if you can share any errors you are getting. Use the console of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass you token in 'X-Auth-Token' header parameter.

Comment: when i am using this   xhrreq.setRequestHeader('X-Auth-Token', `${headerToken}`) it gives me cors issue error do you know how to use it?

Comment: On the server side you'll have to implement the CORS headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or set it to the URL you are using on the client side. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @Daantje i have added this on the URL there I am checking if there is an authorization token in the header that shows a certain page and if the authorization token is not there shows an error page. and when I am using the above code it returns the correct page HTML then If i redirect to the URL it sends me on error page